# Non ascii characters in link_to is causing the app to fail in internet explorer 9 in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, utf-8, internet-explorer-9

I have a recipe search form in my rails app. In a recipe's detail, I have a link to return to the results. The line I added is:

```
link_to "Return to search", :back
```

In Internet Explorer 9, because the :back link has a utf-8=✓ in the url, I get an encoding error. The description of the error is:

ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8)

Let there be known the encoding in my application.rb is set to utf-8. I'm using ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: What's the value of `config.encoding` in your `application.rb`?

Comment: The value is utf-8. Let me add the comment to the question.

Comment: i think that this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086823/invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8-on-page-request/7997412#7997412

Comment: I think that can be a solution. But isn't there another solution(without writting a middleware for the app) to make the link_to helper accept the checkmark as a valid string?

Answer (score 0):

On Ruby 1.9.x you should specify the encoding on each .rb file. Add this on the first line of each:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
```