# Very weird encoding error happening only sometimes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, haml

We're using Rails 3.2.3, Ruby 1.9.1, and HAML. We have a Post model and there is something very weird happening only sometimes and only in Internet Explorer 9.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT):
```

The error is in the following line:

```
= raw @post.content
```

Wich returns the post's content from the database. Note the content has HTML tags.

Weird things are:

- The error only shows on some machines with IE 9. (We can't reproduce the error in other machines using the same IE 9 build)
- The error only happens sometimes.

We've tried this wit no luck (same error):

```
= raw @post.content.force_encoding('utf-8')
```

Any insight? Thanks in advance.

**Update**
After a few changes now the error shows up in the following line:

```
37:         .social
```

There is nothing weird in that line, just spaces (not tabs) and the ".social" string. This is crazy.

Comment: Can you share a bit more of your code and what you are trying to do ?

Comment: Here is the full HAML view https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4515172/problematic_view.html.haml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally found the issue. It was a

```
 = link_to "Back" :back
```

It's better explained here:
[Non ascii characters in link_to is causing the app to fail in internet explorer 9 in rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071271/non-ascii-characters-in-link-to-is-causing-the-app-to-fail-in-internet-explorer)